# RDLC with subreports(2008) send as attachmentmail

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sendmail, rdlc

My Problem is:
I have a file print.aspx that open the report rdlc,

when from the page overview I open the report (with a button) It opens without error.
when I want to open it for email attachment is without subreports.

-I don't know how to call the print.aspx for the mail 
-I don't understand why is without subreports
-I tried with and without FileStream

```
    Dim arrByte As Byte() = localReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, mimeType, encoding, fileNameExtension, streams, warnings)
    'If boolIsMail Then
    'Using fs As New FileStream(strProtName + "." + fileNameExtension, FileMode.Create)
    '    fs.Write(arrByte, 0, arrByte.Length)
    '    fs.Close()
    'End Using
    Session.Add("filename", strProtName + "." + fileNameExtension)
        'Else
        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = mimeType
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strProtName + "." + fileNameExtension)
        Response.BinaryWrite(arrByte)
        Response.End()
    'End If
```